# repackage an rpm from an installed rpm

Tags: linux, rpm

On linux can we repackage a installed rpm if so how.I remember that the a rpm can be generated from the installed binaries

```
  rpm -??? > my.rpm
```

Also the later  i.e, the newer rpm should work on a different machine

Comment: This is possible, but not with the `rpm` command. I had a perl script at one point that did this; it crafted a spec file based on the output of `rpm` and did a "build" which just copied the installed files from the system. I'll see if I can dig it up this weekend.

Comment: I found this and this is how to repackage an rpm from the rpm command http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/programming-scripting/417882-how-create-rpm-fron-installed-packages.html But still wating for your perl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but not with the `rpm` command. I wrote a perl script that does this; it crafts a spec file based on the outputs of `rpm -q` and does a "build" which just copies the installed files from the system.

You can find it here: https://github.com/cormander/rogue-beret-tools/blob/master/scripts/rpm-repack

Usage example, re-packaging the `mailx` rpm:

Query it:

```
$ rpm -ql mailx
/bin/mail
/etc/mail.rc
/usr/bin/Mail
/usr/lib/mail.help
/usr/lib/mail.tildehelp
/usr/share/man/man1/Mail.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mail.1.gz
```

Repack it:

```
$ ./rpm-repack -p mailx
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.9773
+ umask 022
+ cd /usr/src/redhat/BUILD
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-comment-note
Processing files: mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2
Provides: mailx
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires: libc.so.6 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) rtld(GNU_HASH)
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /tmp/tlkN4yrYEi
Wrote: ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2.i386.rpm
```

Query the newly built package:

```
$ rpm -qpl ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2.i386.rpm
/bin/mail
/etc/mail.rc
/usr/bin/Mail
/usr/lib/mail.help
/usr/lib/mail.tildehelp
/usr/share/man/man1/Mail.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mail.1.gz
```

The code isn't at all elegant, but functional. It does copy a lot of the rpm info (everything from `rpm -qi` and most of the scripts), but it isn't by any means comprehensive. Also, it can't copy the GPG signature, nor will it have the same checksums as the original RPM file.

**NOTE:** This is not a "proper" way to build and distribute RPM packages, and was mainly written for troubleshooting and educational purposes.

Comment: at some point this might have been a good answer but the github repo in no longer there.

Answer (score 4):

There is also rpmrebuild
[http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a simple but "tricky" way; it is just : `rpm -e --repackage package-name`
It will output the RPM in `/var/spool/repackage/`.

Example:

```
# rpm -e --repackage samba3x-client
# file /var/spool/repackage/samba3x-client-3.5.4-0.83.el5_7.2.i386.rpm
/var/spool/repackage/samba3x-client-3.5.4-0.83.el5_7.2.i386.rpm: RPM v3 bin i386 samba3x-client-3.5.4-0.83.el5_7
```

Why tricky? Because it actually **remove** the program prior packaging it, just so you know.

Comment: `--repackage` doesn't seem to be available anymore in RHEL7.

Comment: I think that --repackage is not available on RHEL, Oracle Linux and CentOS since version 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think that most rpm based distributions how have official package rpmrebuild (or in the almost official 3'rd party repos like epel, rpmfusion ... etc). I think nowadays this would be your best option for repackaging installed packages.