# I want to remake rpm package without srpm

Tags: compilation, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

1. Goal

   I have a rpm package, but I want to substitute several files in the rpm, and make a new rpm.
2. Backgroud

   I couldn't find srpm of a certain software. What I could download is the rpm package.
3. Operations

   a. I got the spec file from the rpm by `rpmrebuild --package --notest-install -sxxx.spec xxx.rpm`

   b. I got all the files in the rpm by `rpm2cpio pkgname | cpio -ivd`

   c. I copied the files from above into ~/rpmbuild/SOURCE, and copied the xxx.spec to ~/rpmbuild/SPECS

   d. I did `rpmbuild -bb xxx.spec` but I found `File not found:` for every file.
4. Question

   I don't know how to solve this problem. Should I make a tarball of the files from `rpm2cpio pkgname | cpio -ivd` and then go to modify the spec file?

   Or I must install the rpm first and then try to run `rpmrebuild` to create a new rpm?

   I want to know the traditional way to solve this problem, thanks very much.

Comment: I didn't know there was a way to regenerate a spec file from an rpm. Probably some errors slipped into that spec file; I think you should adapt the spec file to make it work; probably you are on a good track.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850772/repackage-an-rpm-from-an-installed-rpm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [repackage an rpm from an installed rpm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850772/repackage-an-rpm-from-an-installed-rpm)

Comment: It's very kind of you. Thanks for all of your help. I checked your suggestions, I know three ways to regenerate a rpm from current installation of this rpm. 

The first one is to use `rpm-repack`, and the second one is to use `rpm -e --repackage package_name`,and the last one is to use `rpmrebuild`. But 

unfortunately, those ways couldn't solve my problem. Because I need to substitute some of the original files in the rpm, so I wonder I must modify the spec 

file so that I could achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You relly need to open up that spec and adapt it to the files it expects. 
The spec file itself holds the answer to most of your questions:

- The `Source` tag(s) will tell you the source files that are needed and their names.
- The `%files` section will tell you what files are expected to be in the in the rpm **after** building it.

I advise you to open another question and post the spec file and a list of the files you extracted wit `rpm2cpio`